# Array of object become blank in node js

Tags: node.js, express

I am new to node js, and try to fetch data from various tables. i got proper data from 1st query but inside that loop my array of object become null. below is my code please let me know if any changes require.

```
connection.query(`SELECT * FROM featured_tags WHERE status = 1 order by id desc`, function (error, results, fields) {
        if (error) {
            res.json({
                status:401,
                message:'there are some error with query'
            })
        }else{
            var featured_tagdataset = [];
            var itemdata = [];
            if(results.length >0){
                for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                    var row = results[i];
                    var featurtag = {};
                    featurtag.id = row.id;
                    featurtag.featured_tag = row.featured_tag;
                    connection.query("SELECT * FROM `items` WHERE status = 1 and FIND_IN_SET('"+ row.id +"' ,featured_tags) > 0", function (error1, itemresult, fields) {
                        if(itemresult.length > 0){
                            for(var l=0; l < itemresult.length; l++){
                                var itemrow = itemresult[l];
                                var item = {};
                                item.id = itemrow.id;
                                item.category_id = row.id;
                                item.name = itemrow.item_name;
                                itemdata.push(item);
                            }                               
                        }
                        console.log(itemdata);
                    });
                    featurtag.tag_items = itemdata;
                    featured_tagdataset.push(featurtag);
                }
            }
            res.json({
                status:200,
                message:'item list',
                data: featured_tagdataset
            });
        }   
    });
```

I am able to get data in console.log(itemdata); but in featurtag.tag_items = itemdata it show me blank array. like below

```
"data": [
    {
        "id": 4,
        "featured_tag": "User's Choice",
        "tag_items": []
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "featured_tag": "Recomanded",
        "tag_items": []
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with the way that you are doing this, but it appears that your main problem is based on your understanding of promises. `connection.query(...)` returns a promise with the data you are attempting to leverage inside of it. Because it is a promise and not an immediate return of data, you will not be able to access it the way that you anticipate.

If you are certain that this is the approach you want to take, you need to look into leveraging and `async-await` inside of your function, that way you have the data you are looking for prior to going to the next iteration of your loop.

Another approach could be leveraging [sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/), and using an `include` in your query to automatically include the data in your query. I'm sure you could also pass a more complicated sql query as well to include all the information in one query, but just some potential advice for moving forward.

===========================================================================
Edit:

Here's an untested example where I tried to modify your code to fit the async pattern. I think, though, that you should definitely modify this to perform this as a single query instead of looping through results.

```
async function test() {
    let results;
    try {
        results = await connection.query('SELECT * FROM featured_tags WHERE status = 1 order by id desc');
    } catch (e) {
        return res.status(401).json({message:'there are some error with query'});
    }

    var featured_tagdataset = [];
    var itemdata = [];
    if (results.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            var row = results[i];
            var featurtag = {};
            featurtag.id = row.id;
            featurtag.featured_tag = row.featured_tag;

            // Get item results
            let itemresult;
            try {
                itemresult = await connection.query("SELECT * FROM `items` WHERE status = 1 and FIND_IN_SET('"+ row.id +"' ,featured_tags) > 0");

            } catch (e) {
                // Handle error
            }
            if (itemresult.length > 0){
                for(var l=0; l < itemresult.length; l++){
                    var itemrow = itemresult[l];
                    var item = {};
                    item.id = itemrow.id;
                    item.category_id = row.id;
                    item.name = itemrow.item_name;
                    itemdata.push(item);
                }                               
            }
            console.log(itemdata);
            featurtag.tag_items = itemdata;
            featured_tagdataset.push(featurtag);
        }
    }
    return res.status(200).json({message:'item list', data: featured_tagdataset});

}
```

Comment: How i can improve this code using async - await.can you give me idea about this?

Comment: I'll add an example of an approach, though I can't test this.

Comment: i am checking it now but i got error like Error: Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined]. my route file is look like module.exports = function(app) {
  var todoList = require('../controllers/api-controller');
  // todoList Routes
  app.route('/list_menu').get(todoList.list_menu);   
 };

Answer (score 0):

One way of async is :

```
connection.query(`SELECT * FROM featured_tags WHERE status = 1 order by id desc`)
.then(results=>{
   //Query was successful and has given results, all your code in this block
}).catch(err=>{
   res.status(401).json({err})
}
)
```

Comment: TypeError: connection.query(...).then is not a function